# Cannot create new RAID with LSI3008 after initial setup

Tags: raid, lsi

I have a LSI 3008 Raid Controller on my server mainboard, and 6 HDDs installed.
4 of them in RAID10 and 2 in RAID1. Now I'm trying to add 2 more HDDs with 2TB each, and after installing them into the machine I enter the LSI config utility.
Now all online sources tell me to go to RAID properties and then set up a new RAID. Only problem is, there is no such option. I'm 99% sure that that's exactly the way I set up the first two RAIDs, but it just doesn't show the option anymore.

I already went through pretty much every single dialog in the utility, there is no such thing as set up new RAID or anything along those lines.

The drives are recognized though and show up in the SAS topology. They are from the same manufacturer but are different drives. Both 2TB.

They are also not new, there might be data on them, which I don't need.

Any ideas?

edit: The HDDs are SATA, but connected through a SAS controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been messaging the SuperMicro support the other day and today they told me that those RAID controllers always support up to two RAIDs, not three. So that's the answer, after two RAIDs you cannot create a new one.